# fread() function prints an extra line of random characters

Tags: c, malloc, fread

I am trying to read data from a file and save it to a struct and print it to a screen. Everything works but it print and extra line of characters . I tried using malloc but I don't think I am using it correctly. Here is the code.

```
void SearchItem(struct grocery NewList) {
    struct grocery NList;
    char sitem[50];
    
    NList.list = fopen("grocerylist.txt", "r");

    if (NList.list == NULL) {
        printf("File could not be opened. \n");
    } else {
        fseek(NList.list, 0, SEEK_END);
        int sz = ftell(NList.list);
        rewind(NList.list);
        char *Data = (char *)malloc(sz + 1);
  
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(Data); i++) {
            fread(&NList, sizeof(struct grocery), 1, NList.list);
         
            if (NList.item_name != NULL) {
                printf("\n %s %.2f %d", NList.item_name,
                       NList.unit_price, NList.quantity);
            } else {
                 printf("Item unavailable.\n");
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(NList.list);
}
```

Here is the output from file

[image]

and here is the contents of the file

[image]

How do I Fix This

Comment: Look at the value returned by `fread()` to see whether it was successful or not.  You ignore what it returns — you've no idea what's valid and what isn't valid.

Comment: The file you've shown is not formatted properly for reading as binary. `for(int i = 0; i<strlen(Data); i++)` uses `Data` which is uninitialized other than the 0 terminator. `fread(&NList, sizeof(struct grocery), 2, NList.list);` tries to read 2 structures into the address of one. Even if your file was formatted properly for this to work you'd have a problem here. Reading/writing structs with pointers in them as binary is a recipe for sadness.

Comment: Side note: Your program would be easier to read (both for yourself and other people) if you used consistent indentation.

Comment: Enable all warnings to see why `Data[sz] = "\0";` is bad.

Comment: ... and post a [mre] instead of dumping all the code you are working on.

Comment: Okay so Some of your comments were kinda harsh, as I am a beginner coder and I am learning. That being said, I will try all of your suggestions. and let you all know what works

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ninja Can you suggest a better way to get this done?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Its Says [Error] assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion] 
When I googled the error its say that happens when I assign  a string to a pointer

Comment: @RetiredNinja  I Used ` fread(&NList, sizeof(struct grocery), 2, NList.list);`  Because  it chopping the last line and printing garbage.    when I used `fscanf()`  all my values were printing in the string variable only, the float and integers variables just showed 0. fread() prints them in their variables, except the last line.

Comment: @AllanWind  first time I heard of it, Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I made the changes, please see my output, this was original issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all your comments they led me to a solution.

Here is what fixed my code,

`while(!feof(NList.list))`

I Changed the for loop back to a while loop and

`fscanf(NList.list, "%[^ ] %f %d\n", NList.item_name, &NList.unit_price, &NList.quantity);`

Instead of `fread()` I used the `fscanf()` and instead if using `%s` for the string, I used `%[^ ]` and the `\n` allowed it to read the next line.

Comment: For safety, instead of `%[^ ]`, you should use `%49[^ ]` if `Nlist.item_name` has a length of `50`. Furthermore, you should check that the return value of `fscanf()` is `3`, the number of requested conversions.

Comment: To stop the loop, do not use `while(!feof(NList.list))`, just test the return value of `fscanf()`: `while (fscanf(...) == 3)`

Comment: Read [Why is `while ( !feof(file))` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)